# How to iterate a List<List<String>> and create a single list?

Tags: java, stream, flatmap

I am working on a legacy code which has a `List<Student> studentList`.
 Each student object contains two properties
`String name;`
`List<Address> address;`

Class `Address` contains two properties `houseNumber` and `streetNumber`

I want to create a single List which contains `name, houseNumber, streetNumber`.
houseNumber is an enum so I'll do `.toString()` and an `if` condition for null values.

```
final List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList
        .forEach(x -> {
                    x.getAddressList()
                            .forEach(y -> {
                                finalList.add(x.getName);
                                finalList.add(y.getHouseNumber != null ?
                                        y.getHouseNumber.toString() : "");
                                finalList.add(y.getStreetNumber);
                            });
                }
        );
```

I have written this code but I want it to achieve the result by using flatmap. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you want this:

```
var rs = lst.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getAddress().stream()
            .map(y -> List.of(x.getName(), 
                y.getHouseNumber() != null ? y.getHouseNumber().toString() : "",
                y.getStreetNumber())
         )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`rs` is list of list contains name, houseNumber, streetNumber.

Comment: Thanks but I want a `List<String>` not `List<List<String>>`

Comment: Oh, it is simple, just flat it `rs.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: simplified it by using `.flatMap` in place of `.map` and replaced `List.of` with `Stream.of`

Answer (score 3):

For each student create a stream of name and a flatmapped stream containing each `Adress`´s `houseNumber` & `streetNumber` concat this streams and flatmap and finaly collect:

```
List<String> finalList = 
    studentList.stream()
           .flatMap(student -> Stream.concat(
                    Stream.of(student.getName()),
                    student.getAddress().stream().flatMap(address ->
                         Stream.of(address.getHouseNumber() != null ? address.getHouseNumber().toString() : "",
                                  address.getStreetNumber()))))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java Stream API to do this. I haven't understood what exactly you want to obtain as a result, so in the following example I concatenate the different parts into one String. (For more info check out the official API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

```
studentList.stream()
            .map(l -> l.getAddressList())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(y -> 
                  y.getName() + " " 
                  + (y.getHouseNumber() != null ? y.getFieldResultStatus().toString() : "") + " " 
                  + y.getStreetNumber());
            })
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How are you accessing `y.getName` in the mapping as it is giving compilation error?

Comment: I wan to add each element in the list separately not concatenating all entries.

Comment: @AnamQureshi I have added the missing () to the method calls, to fix compilation errors.